# Sugarcrm: How to filter the accounts according to the type in a relationship field from contacts?

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, sugarcrm

I have a field account_type in accounts where it has values Resseller, Partner etc.
Accounts has 1:N relationship with contacts.
I created a custom field in Contacts of account_type_c where it has same values as of accounts modules.

So, when creating a contact if user select Resseller, in the related field for Accounts it should show only accounts of type Resseller.
Currently, we have to go to account and create filter here for accounts and than it show accordingly.
But I want it to automatically show users the related accounts as per the type selected in the contact.

I am using SugarPro 7.2.x.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the custom record view of accounts i.e. record.php and in the reseller field added following to array:

```
filter_populate' => 
                array (
                  'account_type_c' => 'Resellers',
                ),
```

Also, use this [link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.5/20_UI_Model/30_Views/05_Filters/) for further reading.